# XAML Binding data

Tags: xaml, binding

If I am a newbie at XAML. I try to bind data from C# object. The problem is that the ListView have correct groups but don't have any items. I tried manipulate XPath but it's seems not working.  I've spent many hours on this and have no idea how to get it to work. Can anyone help?

XML:

```
<Fasteners xmlns="">
            <Fastener 
                Type="Anchor Rods"
                TypeImage= "C:\TEMP\Images\Anchor Rods.png"
                Manufacturer = "Hilti"
                ManufacturerImage ="C:\TEMP\Images\Hilti.png"
                Product = "Hilti HAS-U 8.8"
                ProductImage="C:\TEMP\Images\Hilti.png"                     
                >
            <Item Name="Hilti HAS-U 8.8 M8x110" BlockName="Hilti HAS-U 8.8 M8x110" ItemImage="hilti"></Item>
            <Item Name="Hilti HAS-U 8.8 M8x150" BlockName="Hilti HAS-U 8.8 M8x150" ItemImage="HiltiHASU"></Item>
            <Item Name="Hilti HAS-U 8.8 M8x160" BlockName="Hilti HAS-U 8.8 M8x150" ItemImage="HiltiHASU"></Item>            
            </Fastener>

            <Fastener
                Type="Anchor Rods"
                TypeImage= "C:\TEMP\Images\Anchor Rods.png"
                Manufacturer = "J-FiX"
                ManufacturerImage ="C:\TEMP\Images\Hilti.png"
                Product = "J-FiX Stud 8.8" 
                ProductImage="C:\TEMP\Images\Hilti.png" 
                >
                <Item Name="J-FiX Stud 8.8 M8x110" BlockName="Hilti HAS-U 8.8 M8x110" ItemImage="HiltiHASU"></Item>
                <Item Name="J-FiX Stud 8.8 M8x150" BlockName="Hilti HAS-U 8.8 M8x150" ItemImage="HiltiHASU"></Item>
                <Item Name="J-FiX Stud 8.8 M8x160" BlockName="Hilti HAS-U 8.8 M8x150" ItemImage="HiltiHASU"></Item>
            </Fastener>

</Fasteners>
```

C# object:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Item")]
    public class Item
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "BlockName")]
        public string BlockName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ItemImage")]
        public string ItemImage { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Fastener")]
    public class Fastener
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Item")]
        public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TypeImage")]
        public string TypeImage { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Manufacturer")]
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ManufacturerImage")]
        public string ManufacturerImage { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Product")]
        public string Product { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ProductImage")]
        public string ProductImage { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Fasteners")]
    public class Fasteners
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fastener")]
        public List<Fastener> Fastener { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
        public string Xmlns { get; set; }
        
    }
```

CS:

```
public FastenersDialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Fasteners fasteners = null;
            string path = @"C:\TEMP\Fasteners.xml";
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Fasteners));
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
            fasteners = (Fasteners)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();

            FastenerList.ItemsSource = fasteners.Fastener;
            CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(FastenerList.ItemsSource);
            PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Type");
            PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription2 = new PropertyGroupDescription("Manufacturer");
            PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription3 = new PropertyGroupDescription("Product");
            view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
            view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription2);
            view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription3);
        }
```

XAML:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="185*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="309*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView Name="FastenerList"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" Height="200" Width="494" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SelectionChanged="FastenerList_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Product" Width="275" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Fastener, XPath=Name}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate >
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="False" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <DockPanel >
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="DarkSlateGray" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="bottom" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="12" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text=" item(s)" FontSize="16" Foreground="Gray" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                </DockPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <ItemsPresenter Margin="25,0,0,0"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander>

                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
        <DockPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="70" Width="400" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="47,0">
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <CheckBox Name="DetailOnlyCheckBox" Content="Insert As Detail Only" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"></CheckBox>
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel Width="400" Margin="-130,0,0,0">
                <Button Name="InsertButton" Width="50" Height="25" Margin="0" Click="InsertButton_Click">Insert</Button>
            </DockPanel>
        </DockPanel>


    </Grid>
```

[XAML Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfgHl.png)